# What could be the reason for my internet connection being interrupted every so often?

Tags: network, wifi, ventura, router

My internet connection on a new Mac (Apple M1 Pro, macOS Ventura) has interruptions every so often. Some important information:

1. These interruptions do not happen with other devices that make use of the same internet connection, also WiFi.
2. These interruptions do not "lose" the Wifi connection (meaning, the computer seems to remain connected with the upper right symbol of three arcs in the OS).

I cannot understand what causes interruptions specifically on this computer, and rather than looking immediately for a solution, I would like to at least be able to diagonse the problem. My thoughts are that maybe:

1. The KVM switch sits too close to the laptop and causes some distruptions (I read somewhere this *could* be a problem). Is it indeed at all right? I also tried to put it away by elevating it from the laptop by about 12", and it still doesn't help).
2. There is some bad routing happening and a clash with another machine where my laptop "loses" every so often, but I don't know (a) why that would be the case - I never configured anything in the router; (b) how to check for that?
3. Some hardware problem with WiFi chip in the laptop itself, but again, I don't know how to diagnose that.

Are there any suggestions how to proceed with something like that? I did try to search for solutions and hints online, but they are all very very generic (turn off the router, turn it back on, reboot your laptop, etc. -- all done and tried).

Comment: How long do the interruptions last and how often?

Comment: @Alper I would say once every so often, perhaps once an hour of consecutive use, for 30 seconds to a minute.

Comment: Have you seen the suggestions in the article "[Mac Connected to WiFi but No Internet](https://iboysoft.com/howto/mac-connected-to-wifi-but-no-internet.html)"? It is one of the most comprehensive I have seen.

Comment: There’s conflicting info here… Which Mac do you have specifically; an M1 Pro *Desktop* or a MacBook Pro M1?.  You say that the drops don’t happen on other machines using the same connection **also WiFi** then say WiFi stays connected.  Which one is it?   Why would a KVM have anything to do with your network?  As for “the laptop” which computer is that?  Finally, where is the “bad routing” diagnosis coming from?  Can you provide some clarity with an [edit] to the question?